# Webform- Existing contact- Contact ID option not returning results

Tags: webform-civicrm

I'm trying to build a webform to allow users to add contact details using the contact id, from existing contact

[image: existing contact configuration]

But the lookup doesn't seem to be working on the form itself, I enter a contact id of the corret contact type, and the fields refuse to fill.

[image: blank look up]

Does the contact id option not act as a look up? Have I misconfigured something?

D= 7.65
Civi= 5.13.4

Comment: I can expose contact id in the autocomplete window, which nearly gives me what I was aiming for. It'd be nice to get the contact id lookup function working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not an autocomplete; it’s a lookup. So enter the contactid and then click elsewhere to leave the field.

When I implemented this I did so for Individuals and though theoretically it should probably mostly work for Households - I’ve never tested it as we don’t use Households with any of our clients.

Comment: Thank you, Karin,

Enter id then click away works.

I was hitting the return key and being taken back to the start of the form.

I'll get it working with contact id lookup, and autocomplete field with contact id exposed and see what the client prefers.

Comment: Excellent - glad you got that working!